# DataGridView checkBox desmarcando a seleção sozinho

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

Olá, tudo bem? estou com um problema no meu datagridview C#.
Eu marco a checkBox do dataGridView e quando clico em um botão, ela deveria enviar as informações do grid para disparar um novo evento.
Porém, quando eu clico no botão, a seleção é desfeita, como não tivesse sido marcada no datagridview.
o forecah verifica todas as linhas
se tiver selecionado, ele deve pegar as informações do grid, mas não entra nesta condição pois a seleção do checkbox se desmarca sozinho.
Como fazer para que o grid permaneça checado na saida do datagridview

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAgendamentoDoDia.Rows)
        {                

            if (bool.Parse(row.Cells["clChecagem"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))
            {
                verificaChecadoGrid = true;
                atendimento = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["clnCodigoAtendimento"].Value);
                descricao = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["clnDescAtendimento"].Value);

                contador = contador + 1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Você tentou verificar o objeto da linha e não o estado da célula?

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewFormas.Rows)
            {
                var seuObjeto = (SeuObjeto)row.DataBoundItem;

                if (seuObjeto.Checagem)
                {
                    verificaChecadoGrid = true;

                    atendimento = seuObjeto.CodigoAtendimento;
                    descricao = seuObjeto.DescAtendimento;
                    contador = contador + 1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: eu fiz a mesma coisa, porém no evento click de uma label e funcionou rssss